# Apple Review Can't Get Apple Heatlh Permissions

Tags: ios, flutter, applehealth

So I have a flutter app that uses Apple health kit to pull fitness data. During the onboarding process you get a standard screen saying we're about to ask for permissions, you hit ok, and the health dialog pops up.

This works on all my devices and simulators.

However, this doesn't work on the reviewer's device. I can't figure out why, they say they hit ok, and nothing comes up and they're stuck.

I have no idea why, and no clue where to even start debugging this. I can't even come close to reproducing this.

Comment: If your app has already shown the health permissions dialog it won't be shown again.  You need to direct the user to Settings->Privacy->Health to alter permissions.  You should call [`getRequestStatusForAuthorization`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkhealthstore/2994346-getrequeststatusforauthorization) before you ask for HealthKit permissions.  I suggest you test to see if this is the issue by running your app, granting the health permissions and then re-running your on boarding process to see if you get the same problem Apple is reporting

Comment: So the actual problem is they're testing on an iPad which doesn't offer health kit APIs.

Comment: Ok,  so you need to check [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkhealthstore/1614180-ishealthdataavailable) and react accordingly